# Use CASE & COALESCE

Tags: sql-server-2008, case, coalesce

This syntax just gives me an unhelpful error of

> Incorrect syntax near mentorname

What do I update to force this to show the results?

```
SELECT COALESCE(case when
            mentorname LIKE '%Med%' THEN 'MedTronics' end
            mentorname LIKE '%Zi%' THEN 'Zinamice' end
            , 'Total') As [Prov Source]
```

From database1

Comment: Substitute `else` for the first `end` following `'MedTroncis'`  End means end of case, but you clearly have an else. And add a `when` before 2nd mentorname  See [MSFT help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Comment: @xQbert that produces an error of incorrect syntax near LIKE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CASE 
                    WHEN mentorname LIKE '%Med%' 
                        THEN 'MedTronics'
                    WHEN mentorname LIKE '%Zi%' 
                        THEN 'Zinamice' 
               END
            , 'Total') As [Prov Source]
```

Although you could simplify the query and get rid of the `COALESCE` altogether and leave just the `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN mentorname LIKE '%Med%'
            THEN 'MedTronics'
        WHEN mentorname LIKE '%Zi%'
            THEN 'Zinamice'
        ELSE 'Total'
    END AS [Prov Source]
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep this simple, you could accomplish the same thing with nested `CASE` statements and avoid `COALESCE` completely...

```
SELECT 
    [Prov Source] = 
        CASE WHEN mentorname LIKE '%Med%' THEN 
            'MedTronics' 
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN mentorname LIKE '%Zi%' THEN 
                'Zinamice' 
            ELSE
                'Total'
            END
        END
```

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Necessary?  No.  But it illustrates the proper `CASE` statement structure with data familiar to the OP, and incorrectly formatted `CASE` statements were the root of his problem.